# Should I know Objective-C to use Swift today

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to try iOS development as my pet project.
I have no *Objective-C* experience. And use Python as my main language at work.
Is it possible to use only swift today?
Also can I use third-party objective-c packages with swift?

Comment: The only problem exists is that the toolchain that support Swift is still under NDA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can Swift to develop an iOS app without knowing Objective-C. The learning curve is not steep for the Swift language itself, but understanding of the SDK will surely be beneficial to those that have previously developed for iOS with Obj-C. But you can learn the Cocoa Touch frameworks as you go, and the multitude of Objective-C iOS tutorials out there can be easily translated into Swift.

You can also use third-party Obj-C libraries with Swift. As soon as you import an Obj-C file or create one in your Swift project, Xcode will offer to create a bridging-header for you. In this file, you should `#import` all your Objective-C header files that you wish to be visible to Swift files.

Comment: Wrong. You can use it for iOS or OS X.

Comment: In which part of my answer did I suggest that you couldn't use it for OS X?

Comment: I said, "you can use only Swift", clearly answering the OP, i.e. you don't need Objective-C

Comment: Oh man I see what you mean. But it's a terribly unclear sentence without the vocal intonation. It can just as easily be read as meaning only swift can be used for iOS. Or swift can only be used for iOS.

Comment: Cannot change my vote unless you edit.

Comment: @uchuugaka I've amended my answer for clarity

Answer (score 3):

There's no requirement to know Objective-C before learning to program with Swift.

Apps written using Swift can't be submitted to the App Store before the official release of Xcode 6 in the Autumn, though you can play around all you like for yourself in the meantime.

Check '[The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)' on the iBook store (Free) for more information on the language.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the only issue is backward compatibility. Currently, Swift is known to support iOS7+. (well, this can be expanded later) Anyway, I believe this is not a problem for your pet project.

Swift shares runtime and all frameworks(libraries) with Objective-C. You don't need to worry about *feature availability* on Swift. All of the *pure*(which means no C/C+ magic) Objective-C stuffs are expected to be available on Swift. I think we almost can treat Swift as a re-syntaxed Objective-C.

The opposite case may be problematic. Not all of Swift features are available in Objective-C, then some Swift programs may not be available on Objective-C side.

Cited from [Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216):

> The model for importing Swift into Objective-C is similar to the one
>   used for importing Objective-C into Swift. Swift vends its APIs—such
>   as from a framework—as Swift modules. Alongside these Swift modules
>   are generated Objective-C headers. These headers vend the APIs that
>   can be mapped back to Objective-C. **Some Swift APIs do not map back to
>   Objective-C because they leverage language features that are not
>   available in Objective-C.** For more information on using Swift in
>   Objective-C, see Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start development with Swift only. You can safely add third party Obj-C package with swift.